# To get records from two different function in different database using UNION ALL in one single procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to use a procedure in one database and in that file I need to get records from two different databases with different functions using `UNION ALL`. But SQL Server is showing an error

> invalid object names

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[a].[Me_t1_20191025](@StartDate, @EndDate)
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[b].[Me_t2_20191025](@StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Comment: Use `[a].[dbo].[Me_t1_20191025](@StartDate,@EndDate)` - '[database].[schema].[object]'.

Comment: Do you *really* have a database called `dbo`, with schemas called `a` and `b`? `dbo` is the name of the default scehma created on all databases; having a database named that too would be quite confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting the owning schema before the database name.

Try:-

```
SELECT  * FROM [a].[dbo].[Me_t1_20191025](@StartDate,@EndDate)
UNION 
SELECT  * FROM [b].[dbo].[Me_t2_20191025](@StartDate,@EndDate)
```